# How to link two different images in eCognition

Tags: spatial-database, georeferencing, ecognition

I'd like to link two different images in eCognition to find the same pixels on both images. The images have same projection (geog lat/long). How can I do this?

Comment: what do u mean by two different images? either images of different locations or different resolution images?

Comment: different resolution images

Comment: how can u compare the pixel values for two different resolution images? For example if u have 1m and 4m resolution images for the same location, one pixel in 4m image represents four pixels in 1m image. What is your requirement?

Comment: anyway you can add different resolution image to eCognition; when importing the layers, check out the box near 'Use geocoding'. If this works let me know.

Comment: I just wanted to find same pixel locations on both images.

Comment: as I said in the previous comment, add the images with the option 'use geocoding' to be checked out. Make sure the projection system should be same. You can view those two images in viewer. Lets try this option.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what you hope to do with the pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you follow the idea of a change detection - there are rule sets provided in ecognition community.

**Description of one of the Rule Sets that are provided inside of eCognition Community:** A project with both points of time (same pixels on both images) loaded is the basis, respectively the main map. Then for each point of time T1 and T2 maps are created containing only the respective image layers of either T1 or T2. The vegetation is classified on both Maps independently and synchronized with the main map. The actual change detection takes place in the main map, using the features 'Existence of sub-objects'.

Comment: Can you explain how change detection would help, and general steps to change detection in eCognition?

Comment: Description of one of the Rule Sets that are provided inside of eCognition Community: A project with both points of time (same pixels on both images) loaded is the basis, respectively the main map. Then for each point of time T1 and T2 maps are created containing only the respective image layers of either T1 or T2. The vegetation is classified on both Maps independently and synchronized with the main map. The actual change detection takes place in the main map, using the features 'Existence of sub-objects'.